# Cognos 10 content store database

Tags: cognos

Could someone explain to me how to make the link with iew and its source report using the content store database? I want to print to source report for each view. Oracle SQL

Here is my attempt that display all reports contained in the folder where this view is located:

```sql
select 
  obrap.*
, obj.pcmid
, cm.name

from         cmobjnames_base obrap
  inner join cmobjects obj on obj.cmid = obrap.cmid
  inner join cmclasses cm  on cm.classid = obj.classid

where   
  obj.pcmid in (
      select obj.pcmid 
      from         cmobjnames_base obrap
        inner join cmobjects obj on obj.cmid = obrap.cmid
      where obrap.name = 'Vue de rapport de lam Rapport Indicateurs IDFM'
    )
  and cm.name in ('report');
```

Answer (score 1):

The report view is not the child of a report, like a report is a child of a folder.  The report view references a report.  You would need to use the ID values found in a table like CMREFNOORD or something.

But hacking away at the Content Store database is neither supported nor sustainable.  You won't get help from IBM.  If you migrate your environment to the IBM Cloud, you simply won't have access to the Content Store.  All of your scripts will be useless and you would need to update all of that automation to use the SDK.  You should use the Cognos Analytics SDK, probably from Java.  IBM provides documentation and examples in Java.  You may find examples in other languages, but IBM has not updated critical items (like the DLLs C# needs) for many years.